# Конфликт параметров в jQuery UI Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
heightStyle: "content",
active: false
```

Первый параметр отвечает за раскрытие странички аккордеона на весь контент,
второй - за закрытие всех блоков при загрузке страницы.

Но если добавить второй, первый перестает работать.

Существует ли фикс данной проблемы? Использую jquery-1.10.2

Полный набор используемых параметров:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    autoHeight: false,
    heightStyle: "content",
    active: false
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

с параметрами нет никаких кофликтов, контент либо скрыт css **display: none;** убрать этот стиль или не успевает прогрузится тогда вместо **$(document).ready** использовать **$(window).load**